# Return an instance of a class

Tags: java

I have the following classes:

MinMaxArray class:

```
public class MinMaxArray
{
  public static <T> void MinMax(T[] anArray)
  {
    //return an instance of class Pair
  }//MinMax
}//class MinMaxArray
```

Pair class:

```
//Two objects grouped into a pair.
public class Pair<FirstType, SecondType>
{
  //The first object.
  private final FirstType first;

  //The second object.
  private final SecondType second;

  //Constructor is given the two objects.
  public Pair(FirstType requiredFirst, SecondType requiredSecond)
  {
    first = requiredFirst;
    second = requiredSecond;
  }//Pair



  //Return the first object.
  public FirstType getFirst()
  {
    return first;
  }//GetFirst


  //Return the second object.
  public SecondType getSecond()
  {
    return second;
  }//GetSecond

}//class Pair
```

I'm not sure how i can go about returning an instance of the Pair class. Not looking for answers, just a starting point. Thanks

Comment: @Anthales It needs to compromise of the minumum and maxmimum values of the array. Would the `new` operator allow me to do this?

Comment: Well you would for sure need some kind of loop to find the minimum and maximum values, which you could save in some variables and then return an instance of your `Pair` class with the `new` operator, "sticking in" the minimum and maximum value.

Comment: "new" is just an allocation function. It has nothing to do with min. max. functions. Since you don't have a fixed type you have to make sure that the objects in Array are comparable. You can't compare a string with integer unless the comparison method is overridden.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do and review your API- you can't return the instance you want to return from a void method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint is you can create a Pair, with `T` as the two types.